# ClickOnce not replacing App_Data files during re-install

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

I noticed a behavior I don't understand happening with my application's ClickOnce deployment: a database file (Main.accdb) that is marked as a data file isn't replaced in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\AppName after re-installing or installing a newer version.

In the Project Properties > Publish > Application Files I have:

- File Name App_Data\Main.accdb
- Publish Status = Data File
- Download Group = (Required)
- Hash = Include

In the file properties I have:

- Build Action = Content
- Copy to Output Directory = Copy always

When I install my WPF application using ClickOnce *the first time*, the file is found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\AppName. However, if I uninstall, delete the file in that folder, and re-install it is not replaced. In fact, anything removed from that folder isn't replaced by re-installation.

I tried various options for the Publish Status but the same behavior happens regardless of which options I choose. I'm using WPF with C# in Visual Studio 2017.

Why is this happening and how can I make it so that the file is always there when the application installs (or even better, launches)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the App_Data folder behaves differently and the issue can be resolved by using a folder with any name except App_Data.

I can't find this documented anywhere except for a handful of forum posts of users with similar issues, however, I was able to verify that it all works exactly as expected once I changed the folder name.

All that being said, Microsoft does seem to want developers to use App_Data for databases, so perhaps this is an exception to the norm and may not be the right approach for most projects. In my case, it's a desktop application that needs to deploy a local Access database to the user's computer on install and keep it up to date/replaced during re-install and updates.